# How do I graph square waves with varying duty cycles and a specific amplitude?

Tags: matlab, plot

The problem is: Use Matlab to calculate the RMS voltage of a rectangular pulse shaped waveform with a period of 1 ms. The wave should have a minimum peak of 0 V and a maximum peak of 4 V. Calculate the RMS voltage for “ON” time duty cycles of 20, 50 and 80 percent. Also calculate the RMS voltage for a triangular wave of the same voltage levels (going from 0 to 4 volts and back to 0 volts at the end of the period).

I've got code to calculate the RMS voltages for all four of these waves, but I need to graph the three square waves and I'm unsure of how to do so.

I'm aware of the `square` function and the `dutycycle` function, but I don't know how to implement them so that there is a specific amplitude (in this case, 0 to 4). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
% Calculation of RMS value for 20 percent
v_sum = 0.0; % Initial sum is set to zero
% for loop for one cycle
for k = 0.0:1.0:99.0
   if k < 20
       v = 4; % On period
   else
       v = 0; % Off period
   end
    v_sum = v_sum + v.^2; % Sum and Square are implemented
end
% Rms value calculation
v_rms_20 = sqrt(v_sum/100); % Root and Mean implementation
% Display the value
disp(v_rms_20)

%-----------------------------------------
% Calculation of RMS value for 50 percent
% Initial sum is set to zero
v_sum = 0.0;
% for loop for one cycle
for k = 0.0:1.0:99.0
   if k < 50
       v = 4; % On period
   else
       v = 0; % Off period
   end
    v_sum = v_sum + v.^2; % Sum and Square are implemented
end
% Rms value calculation
v_rms_50 = sqrt(v_sum/100); % Root and Mean implementation
% Display the value
disp(v_rms_50)

%-----------------------------------------
% Calculation of RMS value for 80 percent
v_sum = 0.0; % Initial sum is set to zero
% for loop for one cycle
for k = 0.0:1.0:99.0
   if k < 80
       v = 4; % On period
   else
       v = 0; % Off period
   end
    v_sum = v_sum + v.^2; % Sum and Square are implemented
end
% Rms value calculation
v_rms_80 = sqrt(v_sum/100); % Root and Mean implementation
% Display the value
disp(v_rms_80)

%-----------------------------------------
% Calculation of RMS value for triangular wave
v_sum = 0.0; % Initial sum is set to zero
% for loop for one cycle
for k = 0.0:1.0:99.0
   if k < 50
       v = 4*(k)/50; % Up trend period
   else
       v = 4*(100-k)/50; % Down trend period
   end
    v_sum = v_sum + v.^2; % Sum and Square are implemented
end
% Rms value calculation
v_rms_triangle = sqrt(v_sum/100); % Root and Mean implementation
% Display the value
disp(v_rms_triangle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting the amplitude and voltage range you can and offset and scale the result of [square](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/square.html#targetText=x%20%3D%20square(%20t%20)%20generates,with%20specified%20duty%20cycle%20duty%20.) by the amplitude.

`square` function return values in range [-1, 1].

- Add 1 - set the range to [0, 2].
- Multiply by amplitude/2, fix the range to [0, amplitude].

Example (based on MATLAB example of [square](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/square.html#targetText=x%20%3D%20square(%20t%20)%20generates,with%20specified%20duty%20cycle%20duty%20.)):

```
t = 0:1/1e4:5; %Time (X axis).
cyc = 20; %Duty cycle
amp = 4; %Amplitude
cyc20_amp4 = (square(2*pi*t, cyc)+1)*amp/2; %Voltage (Y axis)

%Plot a graph
figure;plot(t, cyc20_amp4);title(['dutycycle=', num2str(cyc), ' amplitude=', num2str(amp)]);
xlabel('t');ylabel('V')
```

Result:
[image]